# Vlookup with different row. Main table's row smaller than the lookup table

Tags: r, dplyr, vlookup

I want to add a new column that contains lookup value to another data.frame that contains more rows.

For example:

Main table:

```
id Product
-----------
1  Laptop
3  Smartphone
4  PC
```

Lookup table:

```
id Price
----------
1  1000
2  700
3  400
4  200
5  100
```

I want to create a new column `Price` in the `Main` table

Expected Result:

```
id   Product      Price
------------------------
1    Laptop       1000
3    Smartphone    400
4    PC            100
```

I've tried `inner_join`, `semi_join` but it's always showing result with 5 rows. I just need to add another column in the existing `Main` table.

Please be noted, I want lookup based on multiple columns (eg. based on id & date)

Comment: The price for ID 4 is 200, so the price for PC in the result should be 200, not 100, right?

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
  
products <- 
  tribble(
     ~id, ~"Prodcut",
       1, "Laptop",
       3, "Smartphone",
       4, "PC"
    )

prices <- 
  tribble(
    ~id, ~Price,
      1, 1000,
      2, 700,
      3, 400,
      4, 200,
      5, 100
    )

left_join(products, prices)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(id)`
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>      id Prodcut    Price
#>   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1     1 Laptop      1000
#> 2     3 Smartphone   400
#> 3     4 PC           200
```

Comment: How if I need to joining by multiple collumns?